# Problem in receiving video data from PHP in Safari Browser

Tags: php, video

I have some problems in building video watching site.
The main point of site is to use url only one time and block download so I made some logics and get data using "echo" on another php.
This is my code.
viedoview.php

```
<video  controls="" style="width:100%; height:100%;" >
  <source src="video.php?vid=<?php echo $token_encrypted; ?>&token=<?php echo $tokenUrl; ?>">

</video>
```

video.php

```
session_start();
// Get Token
$token = $_GET['vid'];

// Get Current Session ID
$prev= session_id();

// Test the session variable token is set
$tokenUrl=$_GET['token'];
if(isset($_SESSION['setToken']))
{
  // This was a one time token and this is your security
  unset($_SESSION['setToken']);

  $token=str_replace(' ', '+', $token);
  // Now we will re-encrypt the token

  $token = openssl_decrypt($token, "aes128", session_id(),0,'0123456789123456');
   // Now Regenerate the session id
  session_regenerate_id();
  // Now re-encrypt the token with a key combination of both new and old ids
  $token = openssl_encrypt($token, "aes128", $prev.session_id(),0,'0123456789123456');

}
else
{
  // If token was not matched, we have changed the id therefore the next script will not be able to decrypt the token
  session_regenerate_id(true);
}
 header("Location: includes\access.php?id=".$prev."&vid=".$token."&tokenUrl=".$tokenUrl);
?>
```

access.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once '../DBConnect.php';
// Decrypt the Token to get back the video file name
$tokenUrl=$_GET['tokenUrl'];
  $database = new dbConnect();  
     $db = $database->openConnection();
     $sql="select isExpired from tbl_uploaded_videos where oneTimeUrl='$tokenUrl'";
   $user = $db->query($sql);
   $result = $user->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
  if($result[0]['isExpired']=='0'||$result[0]['isExpired']=='1') {   
  $vid=$_GET['vid'];

 $vid=str_replace(' ', '+', $vid);
$token = openssl_decrypt($vid, "aes128", $_GET['id'].session_id(),0,'0123456789123456');


// Check if file exists
if(file_exists("../videos/".$token))
{

  // Another important point here is a session id regeneration
  session_regenerate_id(true);  

  $file = "../videos/".$token;

  $file_size = filesize($file);

  $file_pointer = fopen($file, "r");

  $data = fread($file_pointer,$file_size);

  header("Content-type: video/mp4");
   // var_dump($data);
  echo $data;
       $sql="UPDATE tbl_uploaded_videos SET isExpired='0' where oneTimeUrl='$tokenUrl'";
   $user = $db->query($sql);
}
else {
  echo "Error: File Does not exists";
}
}
else
{

}
?>
```

It played well in Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox but not working in Safari.
I can only see black screen.
How can I resolve this problem? I need help

Comment: What have you done so far to try and debug this? `session_regenerate_id` will set a new session id cookie each time, maybe Safari rejects that for some reason (Safari can be harsh regarding cookies, Apple’s attempts to better protect user privacy go a bit far in some regards.) Have you looked at the request and response via browser dev tools? Applying proper URL encoding to the values you transport as GET parameters here might also be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tested a lot with inspect and print_r . but they return exact data. And it says access.php Byte Range0-1. I think the safari video player don't accept the data ,only video file name.

Comment: I guess byte ranges might actually be your problem here - maybe Safari _only_ wants to make range requests when it comes to videos? Your script does handle range requests at all so far, it always responds with the complete video (which is not a good idea to begin with, range requests is something other browsers could benefit from as well.)

Comment: So what do you think about it? How can I resolve it?

Comment: Well you could implement HTTP Range Requests, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests That is something such a video delivery script should support anyway, because it is important for when the user wants to “search” inside the video (skip ahead to a certain position) - without range requests, the browser would have to download the whole video up to that position.

Comment: Thanks for your reply again .I tried a lot but the problem is not resolved yet. If you know well about this part, could you post one small example for reading video source from php output? I don't know well about HTTP Request and MacOS . If you help me i will appreciate your effort. Thanks

Comment: No, this is too broad a topic, and HTTP range requests are not implemented with just two or three additional lines of code. If you want this, then you need to look into the details, and start implementing it.

Comment: Okay Thanks. I will try to implement by myself,  Thanks again for your advice and help.